# Remove scroll if the data is fitted into the display using CollapsingToolbarLayout and Nested ScrollView in android

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout, nestedscrollview

I am using some static data inside `NestedScrollView` when i scroll the image will be collapsing its working fine. But when the screen size is big all my data is fitted into the screen that time i want to disable my scroll. how to do that.

My code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#DD000000"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Cafe Noir"
            android:layout_gravity="center|left"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/textView34"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="119, 2nd Cross Rd, Phase 4, J P Nagar"
            android:textColor="@color/colorsplashDark"
            android:layout_gravity="center|left"
            android:textAlignment="center"

            android:id="@+id/textView35"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView34"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".3"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView13"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/checkin_history_time" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/placename"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/checkin_history_time"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="13dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/address"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:tag="Hover"
                            android:text="2 hours ago\n (3:15 pm)"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorSubText"
                            android:textSize="10dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".3"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/pointsimage"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/home_bounty_icon" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/pointstitle"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/checkin_history_points"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="13dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/pointsdesc"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:tag="Hover"
                            android:text="You earned 10 Points for checkin"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorSubText"
                            android:textSize="10dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/billimage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/verify_places_snap_sample" />



                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/checkin_history_uploadbill"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/checkin_history_uploadphoto_warning"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_home_yourtotal_rewards"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".3"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/verificationimage"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/checkin_history_verify" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight=".1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/verifytitle"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/checkin_history_verification"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="13dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/verifydesc"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:tag="Hover"
                            android:text="Payment SMS verification Successful"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorSubText"
                            android:textSize="10dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/smstext"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:tag="Hover"
                            android:text="Rs 100 was spent XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX on 2015-08-27"
                            android:textColor="@color/capturebill"
                            android:textSize="10dp"
                            android:textStyle="italic" />


                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>




        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```